# why when I "run" Xcode produces a bigger file?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

So I hit cmd+R and the release app is about 5MB, when I hit cmd+B the app is around 3.5MB...

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you tell Xcode to run the application, it builds it with debugging symbols so you can step through the code execution/debug.  These debugging symbols add to the size of the application.  When you simply build the app, the debugging symbols are not included thus it is smaller.

Comment: I'd have thought that ⌘B would use the same build as for the currently selected scheme mode... so if you have 'run' as the selected mode ⌘B and ⌘R would use the same build steps... but now I see that a scheme has a separate 'build' mode that I guess ⌘B uses, and you can set the debug/release mode on that to be different from the debug/release mode used by the 'run' part of the scheme.